# Django 3.x Python 3.x Forms - 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_prefetch_related_lookups'

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have this form below that cause the error.

```
class ErkbRamsis(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.transfer_id = kwargs.pop('transfer_id')
        transfer = Transfer.objects.get(pk = self.transfer_id)
        if 'coach_id' in kwargs:
            self.coach_id = kwargs.pop('coach_id')
            leg = Leg.objects.get(pk = self.coach_id)
        else:
            leg = Leg.objects.filter(service = transfer.service).first()

        super(ErkbRamsis, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['transfer_clients'] = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
            queryset=Client.objects.filter(related_pnr = transfer.service.related_pnr),
            widget=forms.SelectMultiple(),
            required=False,
        )
        self.fields['coach'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(
            queryset=Leg.objects.filter(service = transfer.service),
            widget=forms.Select(),
            empty_label=None,
            initial=leg,                        #### for non assigned legs cause error
            required=False,
        )
        self.fields['coach_clients'] = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
            queryset = leg.clients,             #### for non assigned legs cause error
            widget=forms.SelectMultiple(),
            required=False,
        )

    def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        transfer_clients = self.cleaned_data.get('transfer_clients')
        coach = self.cleaned_data.get('coach')
        coach_clients = self.cleaned_data.get('coach_clients')
        return super(ErkbRamsis, self).clean(*args, **kwargs)
```

**Scenario:**

I have 4 models `Transfer`<= OneToOne => `Service` <= OneToMany => `Leg`<= ManyToMany => `Client`, The form attach the `Client` objects to the `Leg` by clients.add(`Client`). the form cause error when rendering when the `Transfer`.`Service` have no `Leg` objects created and attached to `Service`. The lines cause the error is marked by comment.

**Edit:**

**TraceBack:**

```
Internal Server Error: /traffic/transfers/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\WorkPlace\Django\wing_buzz\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "G:\WorkPlace\Django\wing_buzz\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "G:\WorkPlace\Django\wing_buzz\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "G:\WorkPlace\Django\wing_buzz\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view      
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "G:\WorkPlace\Django\wing_buzz\main\views.py", line 464, in transfers_assign
    return render(request, 'transfers_assign.html', context)
  File "G:\WorkPlace\Django\wing_buzz\venv\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 19, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "G:\WorkPlace\Django\wing_buzz\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "G:\WorkPlace\Django\wing_buzz\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "G:\WorkPlace\Django\wing_buzz\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 171, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "G:\WorkPlace\Django\wing_buzz\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "G:\WorkPlace\Django\wing_buzz\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "G:\WorkPlace\Django\wing_buzz\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "G:\WorkPlace\Django\wing_buzz\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "G:\WorkPlace\Django\wing_buzz\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "G:\WorkPlace\Django\wing_buzz\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "G:\WorkPlace\Django\wing_buzz\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "G:\WorkPlace\Django\wing_buzz\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "G:\WorkPlace\Django\wing_buzz\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "G:\WorkPlace\Django\wing_buzz\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "G:\WorkPlace\Django\wing_buzz\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 209, in render
    nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))
  File "G:\WorkPlace\Django\wing_buzz\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "G:\WorkPlace\Django\wing_buzz\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 992, in render
    return render_value_in_context(output, context)
  File "G:\WorkPlace\Django\wing_buzz\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 971, in render_value_in_context     
    value = str(value)
  File "G:\WorkPlace\Django\wing_buzz\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\html.py", line 373, in <lambda>
    klass.__str__ = lambda self: mark_safe(klass_str(self))
  File "G:\WorkPlace\Django\wing_buzz\venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\boundfield.py", line 33, in __str__
    return self.as_widget()
  File "G:\WorkPlace\Django\wing_buzz\venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\boundfield.py", line 92, in as_widget
    return widget.render(
  File "G:\WorkPlace\Django\wing_buzz\venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\widgets.py", line 241, in render
    context = self.get_context(name, value, attrs)
  File "G:\WorkPlace\Django\wing_buzz\venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\widgets.py", line 678, in get_context
    context = super().get_context(name, value, attrs)
  File "G:\WorkPlace\Django\wing_buzz\venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\widgets.py", line 639, in get_context
    context['widget']['optgroups'] = self.optgroups(name, context['widget']['value'], attrs)
  File "G:\WorkPlace\Django\wing_buzz\venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\widgets.py", line 587, in optgroups
    for index, (option_value, option_label) in enumerate(self.choices):
  File "G:\WorkPlace\Django\wing_buzz\venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 1138, in __iter__
    if not queryset._prefetch_related_lookups:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_prefetch_related_lookups'
```

Comment: Can you share the full traceback?

Comment: Question Edited with full traceback, Done!

Comment: Can you share your models? You should be able to do with with model forms without having to dynamically construct the fields like this

Comment: excuse my little experience, but is it possible to work with multiple models in one ModelForm ? how to achieve that ? you can post answer if you have another way to achieve form scenario and you have already your up vote saved :D

Comment: It's not clear what the purpose of your form is? Perhaps adding your models/views would help